Module QtQuick.Studio.Components for qmake
I'm trying to import QtQuick.Studio.Controls for qmake.
No matter what I try I get this error:
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
module "QtQuick.Studio.Controls" is not installed
I create the project via Qt Quick-Application (compat) and would like to use it together with the designer studio and QtCreator.
After two days of research, I still haven't figured out how to solve the problem. I can't find anything in the documentation either.
When I create a project using DesignerStudio (with cmake) or in QtCreator (not compat and cmake), everything fits with the imports and it works without any problems.
However, I'm looking for a solution for qmake.
Does anyone know a way to solve this?
I have tried all the includes (and leave them in the .pro for an overview)
.pro
QT += quick quickcontrols2 qml uitools widgets gui core

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

resources.files = main.qml 
resources.prefix = /$${TARGET}
RESOURCES += resources

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target


main.cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/ProteinTracker/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}

main.qml
import QtQuick 6.5
import QtQuick.Studio.Controls

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    ArcItem {
        id: arcItem
        width: 100
        height: 100
        fillColor: "#00000000"
    }

}


Searching in documentation.
Asking ChatGPT

QtQuick.Studio.Components are not part of a normal Qt install. Those components are shipped with the Kit that is used by Qt Design Studio. QtDS basically comes with its own Qt plus the components pre-packaged. That's why you don't get any errors when using the import from inside QtDS using the provided Kit.
If you want to use the QtQuick.Studio.Components in a custom Qt or a Qt installed from the maintenance tool, you'll need to add the QtQuick.Studio.Components to that Qt by compiling the following repository, building and installing it.
https://github.com/qt-labs/qtquickdesigner-components
You can find the instructions in the README.md.
mkdir qtquickdesigner-components-build
cd qtquickdesigner-components-build/
cmake -GNinja -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~user/Qt/6.5.4/gcc_64/ ../qtquickdesigner-components
cmake --build .
cmake --install .

