Qt Design Studio project export for Qt Creator - QtQuick.Studio modules not found
QML/QT Design Studio noob here. 
My current goal is to properly set up the tools to work with QML (decided to go with QT Design Studio for editing the QML and Qt Creator with Python (/Pyside) for the code behind.)
Used PyQt before for QtWidget use outside of the two official Qt IDEs.
I'm trying to export a Qt Design Studio created project for use in Qt Creator (as described here), but run into an issue with some imports. A very simple Hello World project causes the same issue.
Windows 10 x64 
Qt Design Studio: 4.5 
QT Creator: 13.0.0 
Kit used: Qt 6.6.3 MinGW x64 \
The auto generated files
ProjectName >> imports >> ProjectName >> Constants.qml 
ProjectName >> imports >> ProjectName >> EventListModel.qml
contain imports from QtQuick.Studio
import QtQuick.Studio.Application
import QtQuick.Studio.EventSimulator 1.0
import QtQuick.Studio.EventSystem 1.0

which throw a "QML Module not found" errors.
Not sure how to make this available to the Qt Creator. I installed both tools at once so I'd expect them to know about one another and find the respective files.
I read a lot about manually adding stuff to the various, auto generated makefiles, but those seem not to be meant for manual changes. I also want to keep the need for C++ code as minimal as possible (as mentioned, preferably using Python/Pyside as code behind).

The internet these days seems purged of content related to QT (Design Studio) and it has been a quite frustrating learning experience so far. The official documentation seems very lazily written and outdated.
Feel free to point out if I'm generally taking the wrong path here. So far it feels like I'm working against the grain with every step :P
Cheers and happy coding.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78335369/module-qtquick-studio-components-for-qmake/78339411#78339411

Did the link I've shared above help? Do I need to give more information in form of an answer. What do you not understand from the shared link?

@iam_peter Thank you, this works. I'm wondering though if it is normal that one has to do it manually?

Creating a project with QtDS will generate you a CMakeLists.txt that contains the following line option(BUILD_QDS_COMPONENTS "Build design studio components" ON). If you follow that variable BUILD_QDS_COMPONENTS you can see that if set to ON it will include a file called qmlcomponents. In this you can see a link to the same repository I've shared above. By including this file the repository is fetched and build automatically.
